# Manipulating a string with data stored from textField - flutter / dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm very new to programming, I'm pretty much copy and pasting code at this point and seeing what works. But I believe I might need to use a thing called a constructor, but I'm not sure how.

I have 3 textFields that take in numbers and store them in day, month, and year.

I then want to take those 3 variables, add them together and then store them in another variable pDay.

When I try to do this I get the error

> error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyTextInput()
  ));
}

class MyTextInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyTextInputState createState() => MyTextInputState();
}



class MyTextInputState extends State<MyTextInput> {

  static String day = "";
  static String month = "";
  static String year = "";

  static String pDay = day + month + year;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Julian Date")),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Center(
                child: new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                      new Flexible(
                        child: new TextField(
                            inputFormatters: [
                              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                            ],
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                hintText: "DAY"
                            ),
                            onSubmitted: (String str) {
                              setState(() {
                                day = str;
                              });
                            }
                            ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                      new Flexible(
                        child: new TextField(
                            inputFormatters: [
                              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                            ],
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              hintText: "MONTH",
                            ),
                            onSubmitted: (String str) {
                              setState(() {
                                month = str;
                              });
                              }
                              ),
                      ),
                      new Text(pDay),
                      SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                      new Flexible(

                        child: new TextField(
                            inputFormatters: [
                              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                            ],
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                hintText: "YEAR"
                            ),
                            onSubmitted: (String str) {
                              setState(() {
                                year = str;
                              });
                            }
                            ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 20.0,),

                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't figure out anything without more code. Is it in `initState`? `build`? `main`? In addition, you kinda need a `StatefulWidget`, If you don't know the keywords, you should try some tutorial first, there is no fast way to learn a language(framework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyTextInput(), theme: ThemeData.dark(),));
}

class MyTextInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyTextInputState createState() => MyTextInputState();
}

class MyTextInputState extends State<MyTextInput> {
  String day = "";
  String month = "";
  String year = "";

  String pDay = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Julian Date")),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Center(
                child: new Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
          ),
          new Flexible(
            child: new TextField(
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10), hintText: "DAY"),
                onChanged: (String str) { // use onChanged
                  setState(() {
                    day = str;
                    pDay = day + month + year; // add this
                  });
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
          ),
          new Flexible(
            child: new TextField(
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  hintText: "MONTH",
                ),
                onChanged: (String str) { // use onChanged
                  setState(() {
                    month = str;
                    pDay = day + month + year; // add this
                  });
                }),
          ),
          new Text(pDay),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
          ),
          new Flexible(
            child: new TextField(
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10), hintText: "YEAR"),
                onChanged: (String str) { // use onChanged
                  setState(() {
                    year = str;
                    pDay = day + month + year; // add this
                  });
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
          ),
        ]))));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now when I try Text(pDay) nothing is printed to the screen. But Text(day) will.

Comment: In order to assist you better, I'd suggest you to share full code.

Comment: Check out the updated answer. I was not sure what you are trying to achieve, so I just created a simple code to show it working.

Comment: yes thank you.This is perfect. I was just printing to the screen as a debug method.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, it's not but what OP asked initially (before updating his post), could only be done using `static`, however in current solution, there is no need to use `static` anymore.